# this.$refs or document are not visible in mounted() unless I use setTimeout

Tags: javascript, vue.js, settimeout, lifecycle

I'm having a weird issue. I thought that `$refs` were available from `mounted()` life-cycle

But if I try to `log` directly it's the object i get undefined:

```
mounted() {
    // logs undefined
    console.log(
      this.$refs.tabsMenu
    ) 
}
```

And after waiting 1ms it's defined and I can get the object

```
mounted() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // logs the object
      console.log(
          this.$refs.tabsMenu
      )
    }, 1) // <-- just 1ms!
}
```

Any thoughts about this?

My (simplified) template looks like this

```
<template>
  <div>
    <baseContainer>
      <ul ref="tabsMenu" id="tabs-menu" class="flex-inline flex w-full">
        <li>Home</li>
        <!-- many more items -->
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
     </baseContainer>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Consider explaining your case because the problem is specific to it. Where is `myref` assigned? Please, provide a template as well.

Comment: I need calculate if all the items in #tabs-menu fit in it, That's why I need to acces de DOM element to calculate avaliable width.. edited the question providing a mimal template

Comment: I'd expect tabsMenu to be available in mounted here. Can you provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can replicate the problem? The question you linked doesn't suggest that it's a known thing. In case there are race conditions, they need to be addressed on per case basis. $nextTick that was just suggested is one of possible ways (and it's mentioned in dupe question).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is because `mounted()` does not guarantee that the DOM has finished rendering. You will need to wait for `this.$nextTick()`:

```
mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
        console.log(this.$refs.tabsMenu) 
    });
}
```

The reason why `setTimeout(callback, 1)` works for you is because you are essentially deferring the callback (which is in your code, accessing the reference and logging it to console) to the end of the callstack, which is when the DOM would've finished rendering.

If you're familiar with using async/await, you can also do this:

```
async mounted() {
    await this.$nextTick();
    console.log(this.$refs.tabsMenu);
}
```

---

**Update**: It seems like your `ref` element is actually contained in another VueJS component `<baseComponent>`. In this case, listening to `this.$nextTick()` on the parent/consuming component is not sufficient, because it doesn't guarantee the inner component is mounted *and* rendered.

If you still need to use this approach, then my only advice is to ensure that the inner `<baseComponent>` emits some kind of event when it is mounted and its DOM has been rendered, e.g. by emitting a `ready` event:

```
// Inside baseComponent
mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.$emit('ready');
    });
}
```

Then, in your parent component, you can listen to the event as such:

```
<baseContainer v-on:ready="onReady">
  <ul ref="tabsMenu" id="tabs-menu" class="flex-inline flex w-full">
    <li>Home</li>
    <!-- many more items -->
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
</baseContainer>
```

Then in the component's code:

```
methods {
    onReady: function() {
        console.log(this.$refs.tabsMenu);
    }
}
```

Comment: `mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      console.log(this.$refs.tabsMenu)
    }) }` is still undefined

Comment: Thanks for your time, but both solutions you suggest i get `undefined`

Comment: I think i figured it out. is possible that is because my ref is  nested inside another component? I changed `baseContainer` for a `div` and it worked

Comment: Yes: in your case, `baseContainer` cannot guarantee the inner ref is available and rendered when the parent component's nextTick is fired. Do you still need to use `baseContainer` as a component? If that's the case, you will need a deeper workaround.

Comment: No, in this case i dont need it ( it just was a div with a class ) but how would that 'deeper workaround'  would look like?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet Basically, the "deeper" workaround will require the parent component to know the rendered state of `<baseComponent>`. This can be achieved by baseComponent emitted some kind of "ready" event when its own nextTick promise have been resolved in its mounted hook. See my updated answer for a possible solution :)