# Cannot access $refs inside mounted function VUE

Tags: vue.js

In my template I have:

```
<apex-chart v-if="followers_options" ref="chart1" height="160" type="area" :options="followers_options"
                                    :series="followers_series"></apex-chart>
```

I'm calling this function on mounted:

```
export default {
        components: {
            app: appLayout,
            auth: authLayout,
        },
        mounted: function () {
            this.uChart()
        },
        methods: {
            uChart: function() {
                    const store = useStore();
                    let weight_series = [];
                    store
                        .dispatch("getWeights")
                        .then((data) => {                        
                        for (var j = 0; j < data.table.length; j++){     
                            weight_series.push(data.table[j].weight);  
                        }
                        console.log(this.$refs.chart1);
                        this.$refs.chart1.updateSeries([{ name: 'Weight', data: weight_series }]);
                        })
                        .catch((error) => {
                            console.log(error);
                        });
                
            }
        }
    };
```

Yet when I look at the console I get undefined on the $refs log and couldn't find updateSeries on the other line.

I've also tried with a plain input tag with a ref but had no luck.

I'm new to vue so any help would be greatly appreciated.

cheers

To see the $ref yet it was undefined.

Comment: try to define const variable called `refs` at top level, like, near to store variable

Comment: There's no followers_options . In case it exists and the code is incomplete, please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can reproduce the problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [this.$refs or document are not visible in mounted() unless I use setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60619183/this-refs-or-document-are-not-visible-in-mounted-unless-i-use-settimeout)